# Shell: print a number with preceding zeros to a variable?

Tags: bash, printf, number-formatting

I want to print numbers in a bash script using the following C format : %05d.
So I have two variables

```
$num1
$num2
```

And when I set for example `num1=12` I would like to have `echo $num2` equals to `00012`. 
How to do that ?

Comment: There is a shell `printf` command that will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
num1=12
printf -v num2 '%05d' "$num1"
```

Note that this sets num2 only once. If you want num2 to always reflect the current value of num1, you need to define it as a function:

```
num2() { printf '%05d' "$num1"; }
```

...and then call it as such:

```
num2
```